Dump table from dynamodb to localstack
I'm trying to setup a localstack via docker for local development and I hit a stump when trying to import a table from our AWS Dynamodb instance.
I dump the table via describe-table:
aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name tableName --profile dev --region ap-southeast-2 > table.json

and then dump it to my localstack:
aws dynamodb create-table --endpoint-url http://localhost:4566 --region ap-sountheast-2 --cli-input-json file://table.json

All I'm getting are the following errors:
Parameter validation failed:
Missing required parameter in input: "AttributeDefinitions"
Missing required parameter in input: "TableName"
Missing required parameter in input: "KeySchema"
Unknown parameter in input: "Table", must be one of: AttributeDefinitions, TableName, KeySchema, LocalSecondaryIndexes, GlobalSecondaryIndexes, BillingMode, ProvisionedThroughput, StreamSpecification, SSESpecification, Tags, TableClass, DeletionProtectionEnabled, ResourcePolicy, OnDemandThroughput

There definitely exists AttributeDefinitions, TableName and KeySchema in the json file.
My awscli version is the following:
aws-cli/2.17.16 Python/3.11.9


Hi,
It seems like your JSON File may not be formatted correctly, I just tested a small sample json file and it worked successfully. Please take a look at this sample on how the data should be formatted.

I had a similar issue, in my case it was due to the output of the describe-table command. In the CLI version I was using (per the documentation, CLI version can impact JSON structure) The command returned a JSON of structure:
{
  Table: {
    ... // all the table properties needed by create-table
  }
}

Using the jq command I created a new temporary file to use as input for the create-table command:
jq -r '.Table' table.json >> newtable.json
This was not enough however because describe-table still provides additional information which cannot be parsed by create-table. A bit of a pain, but I had to manipulate the json a little more to get the desired structure.
